# Delete all rows from MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has been asked many times and I have read through a lot of the answers but I cannot get this to work. I am trying to create a button (PHP/HTML) to delete all records from a table in MySQL. I have a table in my database called tvdbase. I would like to delete all the records from that table but keep the structure. There will not be more than 10 rows in the table at any given time.

This is my code (I have removed all the unnecessary HTML code for this example)

```
<?php include('includes/database.php'); ?>
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    if($_POST){
        //Delete records
        $query = "DELETE FROM tvdbase";
        $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        // Also tried replacing the 2 lines above with:
        // mysqli_query( "DELETE FROM tvdbase" );
        $msg = "Entries Deleted Successfully";
        header('Location:home.php?msg='.urlencode($msg).'');
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- FORM START --> 
         <form role="form" method="post" action="delete_all.php">        
        <!-- BUTTONS START -->
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="home.php" role="button">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" />
        <!-- BUTTONS END -->        
        </form>
<!-- FORM END -->    
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the delete button is just reloads the same page and the data is still in the table. I am still new to PHP and MySQL so please forgive the errors. Can anyone shed some light as to where I'm going wrong?

I have this working for single rows where I have a delete button in an HTML table on each row with the following code:

```
<?php include('includes/database.php'); ?>
<?php
    //Variable
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //Create room select query
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tvdbase
             WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        //Fetch object array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tvDate = $row['tvDate'];
            $tvCourse = $row['tvCourse'];
            $tvRoom = $row['tvRoom'];
        }
        $result->close();
    }
?>
<?php

    if($_POST){
        //ID Variable
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        //Delete room
        $query = "DELETE FROM tvdbase WHERE id = $id";
        $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        // $msg="Entry Deleted";
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                Entry Deleted Successfully
                </div>";
        header('Location:home.php?msg='.urlencode($msg).'');
        exit;
    }
?>

The form action is delete_room.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>
```

Comment: Does this table have any relationship ?

Comment: Do you want DELETE or TRUNCATE ?

Comment: You look for a HTTP GET argument in a HTTP POST request?

Comment: As said @SaadSuri You must have any relationship to other table... Check it out first and try delete all the records...

Comment: Just delete before inserting new row(s)

Comment: If you do have relationship then do a cascade delete

Comment: Your SQL is highly in danger of injection

Comment: remove the on restrict from your foreign key

Comment: @Saad I only have 1 table (tvdbase)

Comment: @Strawberry either would work for me, but if I am not mistaken, TRUNCATE would delete the entire table and recreate it with the same structure which would be best for large tables. Like I say, still new to PHP and MySQL so not entirely sure which would be best. My table will not have many rows. I have tried TRUNCATE as well with no joy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to print something in your IF statement, to check if the code pass through.

If not, try adding in your form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='flag' value='pass'>
```

Then changes your IF in this way:

```
if ($_POST['flag'] == "pass") {

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Soprano this helped. My problem was with the form.